Proving Rigourness in Physics flavored Mathematics proofs
Recently I got inspired by a fish-tank based proof of Pythagoras proof and tried proving a property of Power of Point in Geometry of Circle.
We know that : $$AP.AQ = AT^2$$

Now the physics based proof which I made goes like this :
Consider water to be filled in the section shaded in the above diagram. This makes the APT a tank filled with water. This must be in rotational equilibrium otherwise this will cause perpetual motion. Hence we observe the torque of system about point O. The section of water which applies force at TP curved section will cause zero torque as all are directly passing through the centre of circle. Hence the only Torques we need to concern ourself with are the one's in AT and AP section. These both shout cancel out:
Torque due to AT about O proportional to : $$AT * (AT / 2)$$
Torque due to AP about O proportional to : $$AP * (AP / 2 + PM)$$
Equating both the torque easily gives : $$AT ^ 2 = AP .AQ$$
Now what my question is what makes this physics proof mathematically formal / rigorous enough, or why does these method even work in general.

For a physicist it's completely obscure what kind of force is meant. Perhaps the tank is filled with a gas under pressure? Water does not hold pressure, because its incompressible. The gravitational pressure cannot be meant by the force acting to to the top.

@RolandF Be careful: "incompressible" does not mean "no pressure".

You might be interested in Mark Levi’s The Mathematical Mechanic: Using Physical Reasoning to Solve Problems which is a compilation of physically motivated proofs. It even includes your approach for the power of a circle if I recall correctly.
Yes, you can translate it into a rigorous mathematical proof using calculus. Your starting point is static equilibrium. Via the principle of virtual work from which it can be derived, you can translate the problem geometrically.
Imagine shifting your shaded surface by a small angle $\delta\phi$ about the center $O$. In the one hand the shaded area should not change upon rotation. On the other hand, the variation of the shaded area can be calculated by computing the variations due to its edges.
The area swept by the segment $[AT]$ is:
$$
\delta\mathcal A_{AT}=\frac12AT^2\delta\phi
$$
which physically corresponds to the virtual work of the pressure force on the side $[AT]$.
Similarly the area swept by the segment $[AP]$ is:
$$
\delta\mathcal A_{AP}=\frac12AP\cdot AQ\delta\phi
$$
which physically corresponds to the virtual work of the pressure force on the side $[AP]$.
The equality of the swept out areas is therefore equivalent to the equality of the virtual works which translates into the torque balance. Thus, the key mathematical property beihind the physically based proof is the conservation of area under rotation. It also motivates why you imagine a fluid of uniform pressure within the surface.

I have read the book and in that book this was left as an exercise. Hence I made this setup for proof.... It was just that I was curios what makes this rigorous mathematically.

Right, it’s been a while since I last read it, but the problem looked familiar. Yes, your approach is in the spirit of the book and you can make it rigorous (like all the proofs in it).
